# Javascript: checking forms for validations

Tags: javascript, html

I am playing with the form validation using javascript. so when ever i use (this) keyword in prototype method (Validator) the console is giving me an error that is in this picture [Error from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMWq0.png). so help me

```js
function Validation(id, event, target, regex) {
    this.id = id;
    this.event = event;
    this.target = target;
    this.regex = regex;
}

Validation.prototype.Validator = function() {
    var result = this.regex.exec(this.target.value);
    if(result && this.target != null) {
        alert("you did it");
    }
    else {
        alert('no you didn\'t');
    }
};
    
var object1 = new Validation(document.getElementById('btn'), eventer, document.getElementById('box'), /\w/);

var eventer = object1.id.addEventListener("click", object1.Validator);

var object2 = new Validation(document.getElementById('btn'),
                            eventer2,document.getElementById('passbox'), /\d/);

var eventer2 = object2.id.addEventListener("click", object2.Validator);
```

```css
<style>
        .label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        #box {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        #passbox {
            margin-left: 8px;
        }
      
    </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>playing with forms</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
        <div><span class="label">Username: </span><input type="text" id="box">
         </div>
        <div><span class="label">Password: </span><input type="text"               
       id="passbox"></div>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" id="btn" value="clickme"/>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why building up your own validation script? What about HTML5 Constraint Validation? It will surely do, what you 're trying to code here.

Comment: Yes but i need learn how to do it in my own script i want to be javascript developer. and thanks for that suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the validation function as an event handler and it gets called, the `this` object is set to the element, not to the validator object.  This results in the `this.regex` property being undefined and causing a failed match.

Therefore, you need to make sure the `this` object is bound to the validator instead, and you can do that using:

```
var eventer = object1.id.addEventListener("click", object1.Validator.bind(object1));
```

Comment: it didn't work i tried it gives me an error (this.regex.match isnot a function)

Comment: @Yya09 there is no `match` method on a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Are you using this.regex.exec or this.regex.match?  Regexp class does not have a match function, but has an exec function.  Are you thinking of String.prototype.match perhaps?

Comment: You sure?  It seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2rg7j3bo/

Comment: yeah it now work thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is `Validator` function is assigned as a click  event to a DOM element, so when you say `this`, it will represent this DOM element and not your object. You will have to use `bind()` function to change the context of the function.

Following is the code:

```js
function Validation(id, event, target, regex) {
    this.id = id;
    this.event = event;
    this.target = target;
    this.regex = regex;
}

Validation.prototype.Validator = function() {
  console.log(this);
    var result = this.regex.exec(this.target.value);
    if(result && this.target != null) {
        alert("you did it");
    }
    else {
        alert('no you didn\'t');
    }
};
    
var object1 = new Validation(document.getElementById('btn'), eventer, document.getElementById('box'), /\w/);

var eventer = object1.id.addEventListener("click",object1.Validator.bind(object1));

var object2 = new Validation(document.getElementById('btn'),
                            eventer2,document.getElementById('passbox'), /\d/);

var eventer2 = object2.id.addEventListener("click", object2.Validatorbind(object2));
```

```css
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#box {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#passbox {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>playing with forms</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div><span class="label">Username: </span>
      <input type="text" id="box">
    </div>
    <div><span class="label">Password: </span>
      <input type="text" id="passbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="clickme" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks it works @Rajesh